# Slow Istio setup

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway, istio-kiali

I run a bare-metal Kubernetes cluster on 7 Raspberry Pi 4b with 8GB each.

I also installed [Flannel](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel#flannel) for the communication between the nodes, [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) to have an external Load Balancer, and [Istio](https://istio.io/) to handle the incoming traffic.

To test my setup I run a small Rust application that immediately responds to each request with an HTTP 200. This application runs in the `ping` pod.

This is the yaml to install the pod and everything related to it:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ping-deployment
  labels:
    app: ping
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ping
      labels:
        app: ping
        version: 0.0.4
    spec:
      tolerations:
        - key: "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable"
          operator: "Exists"
          effect: "NoExecute"
          tolerationSeconds: 30
        - key: "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready"
          operator: "Exists"
          effect: "NoExecute"
          tolerationSeconds: 30
      containers:
        - name: ping
          image: dasralph/ping:arm64_0.0.4
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
      restartPolicy: Always
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ping

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ping-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: ping
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      name: http

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: ping-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ping
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - ping-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            exact: /ping
      route:
        - destination:
            host: ping-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

The cluster now looks like this:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE        NAME                                                READY   STATUS     RESTARTS      AGE
default          ping-deployment-5f76577d6-rrrpf                     2/2     Running    2 (10h ago)   10h
default          ping-deployment-5f76577d6-xs8td                     2/2     Running    0             79m
default          prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission-create-b78k8   1/2     NotReady   2             79m
istio-system     grafana-78588947bf-fckfh                            1/1     Running    0             9h
istio-system     istio-egressgateway-5ff98855b6-nvd75                1/1     Running    1 (10h ago)   12h
istio-system     istio-ingressgateway-8695fcdd7b-58576               1/1     Running    0             10h
istio-system     istiod-866c945f4d-dqhzf                             1/1     Running    0             9h
istio-system     jaeger-b5874fcc6-s4t6l                              1/1     Running    0             10h
istio-system     kiali-575cc8cbf-r2xd8                               1/1     Running    1 (10h ago)   10h
istio-system     prometheus-6544454f65-479t6                         2/2     Running    0             9h
kube-system      coredns-6d4b75cb6d-99lr4                            1/1     Running    5 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      coredns-6d4b75cb6d-tmjcx                            1/1     Running    5 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      etcd-raspi1                                         1/1     Running    6 (9h ago)    5d8h
kube-system      kube-apiserver-raspi1                               1/1     Running    5 (9h ago)    5d8h
kube-system      kube-controller-manager-raspi1                      1/1     Running    5 (9h ago)    5d8h
kube-system      kube-flannel-ds-29mdq                               1/1     Running    5 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-flannel-ds-68b2x                               1/1     Running    5 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-flannel-ds-ls8zl                               1/1     Running    5 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-flannel-ds-lz4mw                               1/1     Running    5 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-flannel-ds-vx8kp                               1/1     Running    6 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-flannel-ds-xgv9s                               1/1     Running    7 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-flannel-ds-z28gq                               1/1     Running    5 (9h ago)    5d8h
kube-system      kube-proxy-2p77z                                    1/1     Running    5 (9h ago)    5d8h
kube-system      kube-proxy-6xpkc                                    1/1     Running    5 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-proxy-7ckpf                                    1/1     Running    5 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-proxy-8glss                                    1/1     Running    5 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-proxy-g2gnj                                    1/1     Running    5 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-proxy-kqksp                                    1/1     Running    6 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-proxy-qbl5v                                    1/1     Running    5 (10h ago)   5d8h
kube-system      kube-scheduler-raspi1                               1/1     Running    5 (9h ago)    5d8h
metallb-system   controller-7476b58756-gzvxr                         1/1     Running    2 (10h ago)   39h
metallb-system   speaker-5kgh6                                       1/1     Running    2 (10h ago)   39h
metallb-system   speaker-6ft5z                                       1/1     Running    2 (10h ago)   39h
metallb-system   speaker-cl8n8                                       1/1     Running    2 (10h ago)   39h
metallb-system   speaker-lr6sw                                       1/1     Running    2 (10h ago)   39h
metallb-system   speaker-v27tm                                       1/1     Running    2 (10h ago)   39h
metallb-system   speaker-z5nbl                                       1/1     Running    2 (10h ago)   39h
```

```
$ kubectl get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                      AGE
default        kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                                                                      5d8h
default        ping-service                         ClusterIP      10.97.131.254    <none>        8080/TCP                                                                     11h
istio-system   grafana                              ClusterIP      10.98.194.129    <none>        3000/TCP                                                                     10h
istio-system   istio-egressgateway                  ClusterIP      10.108.47.254    <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP                                                               12h
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway                 LoadBalancer   10.104.219.165   10.0.0.3      15021:31687/TCP,80:31856/TCP,443:32489/TCP,31400:30287/TCP,15443:30617/TCP   12h
istio-system   istiod                               ClusterIP      10.107.79.224    <none>        15010/TCP,15012/TCP,443/TCP,15014/TCP                                        12h
istio-system   jaeger-collector                     ClusterIP      10.100.10.165    <none>        14268/TCP,14250/TCP,9411/TCP                                                 10h
istio-system   kiali                                LoadBalancer   10.108.177.140   10.0.0.4      20001:32207/TCP,9090:31519/TCP                                               10h
istio-system   prometheus                           ClusterIP      10.110.13.41     <none>        9090/TCP                                                                     10h
istio-system   tracing                              ClusterIP      10.101.194.169   <none>        80/TCP,16685/TCP                                                             10h
istio-system   zipkin                               ClusterIP      10.108.22.152    <none>        9411/TCP                                                                     10h
kube-system    kube-dns                             ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP                                                       5d8h
kube-system    prometheus-kube-prometheus-kubelet   ClusterIP      None             <none>        10250/TCP,10255/TCP,4194/TCP                                                 11h
```

```
$ istioctl analyze

✔ No validation issues found when analyzing namespace: default.
```

After everything is set up, I did some tests and found out, that the `ping` is much slower when I access it via Istio.

Benchmark `ping` with **2 pods** via `ping-service`:

```
$ wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s  --latency http://10.97.131.254:8080/ping
Running 30s test @ http://10.97.131.254:8080/ping
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   135.59ms   21.80ms 282.44ms   69.58%
    Req/Sec   244.19     40.80   353.00     70.31%
  Latency Distribution
     50%  133.20ms
     75%  151.27ms
     90%  160.07ms
     99%  205.07ms
  87440 requests in 30.07s, 19.85MB read
Requests/sec:   2908.20
Transfer/sec:    675.99KB
```

Benchmark `ping` with **2 pods** via `istio-ingressgateway`:

```
$ wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s  --latency http://10.0.0.3/ping
Running 30s test @ http://10.0.0.3/ping
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   410.99ms  159.21ms   1.85s    78.58%
    Req/Sec    82.24     37.46   252.00     65.66%
  Latency Distribution
     50%  387.92ms
     75%  475.87ms
     90%  578.71ms
     99%    1.05s
  29030 requests in 30.08s, 4.51MB read
Requests/sec:    965.25
Transfer/sec:    153.61KB
```

With Istio, I get only a third of the throughput when I access it directly. But it gets even worse.

Benchmark `ping` with **6 pods** via `ping-service`:

```
$ wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s  --latency http://10.97.131.254:8080/ping
Running 30s test @ http://10.97.131.254:8080/ping
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    56.22ms   25.90ms 447.45ms   90.03%
    Req/Sec   607.64     62.02     1.78k    73.58%
  Latency Distribution
     50%   49.45ms
     75%   60.03ms
     90%   79.33ms
     99%  168.56ms
  218021 requests in 30.10s, 49.49MB read
Requests/sec:   7243.38
Transfer/sec:      1.64MB
```

Benchmark `ping` with **6 pods** via `istio-ingressgateway`:

```
$ wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s  --latency http://10.0.0.3/ping
Running 30s test @ http://10.0.0.3/ping
  12 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   470.44ms  204.97ms   1.88s    86.25%
    Req/Sec    74.85     34.41   191.00     60.75%
  Latency Distribution
     50%  436.67ms
     75%  528.83ms
     90%  638.73ms
     99%    1.50s
  25720 requests in 30.07s, 4.00MB read
Requests/sec:    855.41
Transfer/sec:    136.15KB
```

**Q1:** Why is the `istio-ingressgateway` much slower than the `ping-service`?

**Q2:** Why is the `istio-ingressgateway` slower with 6 pods? Shouldn't there be a performance boost?

I also installed [kiali](https://kiali.io/) to find the bottleneck but everything I found was this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit:** I found out that I get more details when I click one a bubble in the Traces view:

[image]

[image]

But now I have more questions.

**Q3:** Why do I have Spans with only 1 app involved and sometimes with two apps involved?

**Q4:** It looks that the `istio-ingressgateway` is the bottleneck but how can I fix it?